# Look up an operaton by its Operation.hash

Tags: rpc

Is there a way to look up an operaton by its *Operation.hash* to see if it was applied? I need to run this after a program crash to see if an operation was applied.

I got the response that this is part of the historic data that Taquito doesn't have access to, however, if you have the block hash, you can get the whole block from the RPC and dig into it to find the operation and its status
https://tezostaquito.io/typedoc/classes/_taquito_rpc.rpcclient.html#getblock

But I don't have the block hash, so I'd either need to look at every block or use external indexer like a block explorer?

Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query this directly via the RPC, the RPc only lets you query block by block. You need to use an indexer to query such data. Please have a look at the API docs of tzkt: https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Operations_GetTransactionStatus

Comment: This endpoint is more efficient for OP's needs, and creates much less load on the API ;) https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Operations_GetTransactionStatus